# Map like Candy Crush using Cocos2d-x + Marmalade

Tags: dictionary, cocos2d-x, marmalade, candy

I have developed a 2D game using Cocos2d-x and Marmalade.

I would like to know what would it be the "better solution", considering performances, memory etc, to create a Scene before playing the game where I can show to the user a Map like that one used in Candy Crush Game, then:

- zooamble
- scrollable
- clickable buttons (levels) at predefined coords etc
- character moving between buttons (level)

Many thanks in advance

Sergio

Comment: It would be nice to get some piece of code or some reference to start with.

Comment: Any good tutorials for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CCLayerPanZoom** as parent and add menu items, characters etc as children.

Check this link: [CCLayerPanZoom demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6rkugd-5nU)

and, you can download the source file [CCLayerPanZoom Cpp file](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/1305/CCLayerPanZoom.cpp) and [CCLayerPanZoom header file](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/1306/CCLayerPanZoom.h) from here.

Answer (score 0):

Check out cocos. They have `MissionSelect` in the tutorials. The usage of `ScrollView`.